# `set -e` not working in bash subshell function when called like `if ! func; then ...` or `func || true`

Tags: bash, sh

I have a Bash subshell function like this:

```bash
f() (
  set -e
  ( exit 1 )
  echo "I should not be printed!"
)
```

If I invoke it like this:

```bash
f
```

I get no output, as expected.

But if I invoke it like this:

```bash
f || true
```

or like this:

```bash
if ! f; then : ; fi
```

I get "I should not be printed!" This is not what I'd expect. My expectation is that, since I'm defining `f` using a subshell (`f() ( ... )` instead of `f() { ... }`), this should be equivalent to putting the contents of `f` into its own shell script, then running it as `bash ./f.sh`, in which case I get no output.

So, my question is twofold:

1. Is there a way to get `f` to *always* return when it hits that `( exit 1 )` line, regardless of how it's called, while still keeping it a function? (i.e. without putting the contents of `f` into its own script and invoking it like `bash ./f.sh`?)
2. Is `set -e` not working (a bug in Bash, maybe?), or is this expected behavior? Why does the execution of this function depend on whether it's invoked "bare" (like `f`) or as part of an expression that checks the return code (like `f || true`)?

Comment: Many recommend not using `set -e` precisely *because* it's not always clear what will and will not trigger the script to exit.

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105. This is a must read for anyone contemplating `set -e`.  Key takeway: don't use it.

Answer (score 3):

From the `bash` man page:

> If a compound command or shell function  executes  in  a
> context  where -e is being ignored,

`f || true` and `! f` are such contexts

> none of the commands
> executed within the compound command  or  function  body
> will  be  affected  by the -e setting, even if -e is set
> and a command returns a failure status.

So even though `set -e` appears in the body of the function, the setting is ignored due to the context in which the function is executed.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. Though it seems like a major pitfall, I'll have to accept it. Is there a workaround or is the only option to move `f` to its own script?

Comment: IMO, you should stop using `set -e` and have `f` return a non-zero exit status that the caller can check to decide if the script needs to exit or not.